# ios determine if subviews overlap (hit test?)

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a bunch of subviews and want to determine if the BallView has hit the PaddleView. (I am making a simple version of breakout). What is the best way to do this?

BallView and PaddleView are both subview of BlockBreakerView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CGRect*` functions. Something like `CGRectIntersectsRect()` will accept two rects (for a `ball.frame` and a `paddleview.frame`) and return simple `BOOL` denoting if they overlap.